# I just started learning PHP. How to find and print the longest word in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$array =array("AB","ABC","ABCD","ABCDE","BD");
```

Requirement: find the longest element in the array

```
Output:ABCDE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array =array("AB","ABC","ABCD","ABCDE","BD");

$longstring = $array[0];
foreach( $array as $string ) {
if ( strlen( $string ) > strlen( $longstring ) ) {
$longstring = $string;
    }
}

echo $longstring;
```

Comment: This outputs the actual string. Shivruda's answer will give you the length of the longest string.

Comment: You are welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, make sure to mark the most helpful answer as the right answer so the question is marked as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

First we are iterate the array with help of `foreach` loop. in `foreach` loop we check `$result` is less than array value. if `array` value is greater then `$result` array then we override previous value of `$result` with new value. if we found greatest length than previous array element then we are storing new length & key of new element in variable.

```
   $array =array("AB","ABC","ABCD","ABCDE","BD"); 
    $result = $resultkey = 0;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

        if($result < strlen($value) ) {
            $result = strlen($value);
            $resultkey = $key;
        }
    }
    echo 'longest value:' $result;
    echo 'result :'   $array[$resultkey]
```

Output:

```
longest value:  5
result :ABCDE
```

Comment: Hello
How to output the result is: ABCDE

Comment: @PhúTriệu updated code for result: ABCDE & longest element count

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though it's a bit confusing.

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

$array = array("AB","ABC","ABCD","ABCDE","BD");

$longertext = array_search(max($array), $array)-1; //4-1 =3

// minus 1 because it's counting the actual position not starts with 0 it returns 4

echo $longertext;  //equals 3
echo "\n";
echo $array[$longertext];  //equals  ABCDE

?>
```

The actual test: http://rextester.com/OTI23127

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array by string length using [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and get the first item:

```
$array =array("AB","ABC","ABCD","ABCDE","BD");
usort($array, function($x, $y) { return strlen($y)-strlen($x); });
echo $array[0];
```

Result:

> ABCDE

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LDBsr)